# How to create a new git repository from an existing repository, selecting only specific folders in the repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Let's say I have a git repository with three folders A, B, and C. I want to create a new git repository with just folder C ( without A, B ) but with the history preserved. Basically, I want a new git repo with folders A,B deleted and changes in them removed from the history too; a repo with just folder C and the commits which changed the contents of folder C.

Comment: How would you like the new repository to be like? `C/.git`, or `.git` and `C` at the same level?

Comment: Either should be okay

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the current repository `foo` structure is

```
foo
├── A
├── B
├── C
└── .git
```

To make it be

```
foo
├── C
└── .git

# backup the current branch.
# this can be omitted because
# git filter-branch automatically
# makes a backup as refs/original/refs/heads/<branch>
git branch <backup_branch>

# rewrite the current branch, removing A and B from the history
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter 'rm -rf A B'

# if anything goes wrong
# reset to the original status
git reset refs/original/refs/heads/<branch> --hard
# or
git reset <backup_branch> --hard
```

To make it be

```
C
└── .git

git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter C
```

In either way, the current branch is rewritten and only the commits that have touched C are preserved (the commit sha1 values are changed).

Push the new branch to the new repository.

```
git push <path_to_new_repo> HEAD:refs/heads/<branch>
```